# How many classes YOLOP can detect?

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo, semantic-segmentation

I am running inference of YOLOP and got bounding boxes around the detected vehicles with no labels. I want to know how many classes YOLOP can detect other than vehicles (like pedestrain, traffic signs etc) and how to display labels around detected bounding boxes using YOLOP inference code?

```
python tools/demo.py --source /content/YOLOP/inference/images --device 0
```

Given code just produces output images with bounding boxes around detected vehicles and segmented drivable area.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

YoloP only detects cars, buses, trucks, and trains along with drivable areas and lane lines.

Answer (score 0):

The pre-trained models in the official repository [YOLOP](https://github.com/hustvl/YOLOP/) can detect only car, bus, truck, and train classes. These all are clubbed into a single class.

If you want to detect other classes, you will have to train the model yourself as I haven't found any pre-trained model online.

The dataset used by the authors is BDD100k, which has 10 classes. While loading the dataset, the code replaces the traffic light class with four classes tl_red, tl_green, tl_yellow, and tl_none. So, in total you have 13 classes.